# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, crash

From what I can gather the program has been put into the background Application Stop has been called. The application is brought back into the forground and this is when the error is occuring. The app is unable to load the xml file for whatever reason, the code and xml work everytime on my phone HTC Desire One. Is there anything obvious that I can look at to fix this, or any suggestions as to how to track down this problem?

This is the call stack that I get back from TestFlight.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hdms.manager/com.hdms.manager.Drawable.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity in ActivityThread.java on Line 2247
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity in ActivityThread.java on Line 2297
android.app.ActivityThread.access$700 in ActivityThread.java on Line 152
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage in ActivityThread.java on Line 1282
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage in Handler.java on Line 99
android.os.Looper.loop in Looper.java on Line 137
android.app.ActivityThread.main in ActivityThread.java on Line 5328
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke in Method.java on Line 511
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run in ZygoteInit.java on Line 1102
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main in ZygoteInit.java on Line 869
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView in LayoutInflater.java on Line 619
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView in PhoneLayoutInflater.java on Line 56
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView in LayoutInflater.java on Line 666
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag in LayoutInflater.java on Line 691
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 752
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 495
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 397
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 353
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView in PhoneWindow.java on Line 327
android.app.Activity.setContentView in Activity.java on Line 1928
com.hdms.manager.Drawable.SplashScreen.onCreate in SplashScreen.java on Line 25
android.app.Activity.performCreate in Activity.java on Line 5250
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate in Instrumentation.java on Line 1097
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity in ActivityThread.java on Line 2211
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance in Constructor.java on Line 417
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView in LayoutInflater.java on Line 593
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream in BitmapFactory.java on Line 596
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream in BitmapFactory.java on Line 444
android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream in Drawable.java on Line 817
android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable in Resources.java on Line 2854
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable in TypedArray.java on Line 602
android.widget.ImageView.<init> in ImageView.java on Line 126
android.widget.ImageView.<init> in ImageView.java on Line 116
... 27 more
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView in LayoutInflater.java on Line 619
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView in PhoneLayoutInflater.java on Line 56
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView in LayoutInflater.java on Line 666
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag in LayoutInflater.java on Line 691
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 752
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 495
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 397
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 353
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView in PhoneWindow.java on Line 327
android.app.Activity.setContentView in Activity.java on Line 1928
com.hdms.manager.Drawable.SplashScreen.onCreate in SplashScreen.java on Line 25
android.app.Activity.performCreate in Activity.java on Line 5250
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate in Instrumentation.java on Line 1097
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity in ActivityThread.java on Line 2211
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity in ActivityThread.java on Line 2297
android.app.ActivityThread.access$700 in ActivityThread.java on Line 152
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage in ActivityThread.java on Line 1282
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage in Handler.java on Line 99
android.os.Looper.loop in Looper.java on Line 137
android.app.ActivityThread.main in ActivityThread.java on Line 5328
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke in Method.java on Line 511
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run in ZygoteInit.java on Line 1102
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main in ZygoteInit.java on Line 869
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance in Constructor.java on Line 417
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView in LayoutInflater.java on Line 593
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream in BitmapFactory.java on Line 596
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream in BitmapFactory.java on Line 444
android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream in Drawable.java on Line 817
android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable in Resources.java on Line 2854
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable in TypedArray.java on Line 602
android.widget.ImageView.<init> in ImageView.java on Line 126
android.widget.ImageView.<init> in ImageView.java on Line 116
... 27 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance in Constructor.java on Line 417
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView in LayoutInflater.java on Line 593
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView in PhoneLayoutInflater.java on Line 56
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView in LayoutInflater.java on Line 666
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag in LayoutInflater.java on Line 691
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 752
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 495
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 397
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 353
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView in PhoneWindow.java on Line 327
android.app.Activity.setContentView in Activity.java on Line 1928
com.hdms.manager.Drawable.SplashScreen.onCreate in SplashScreen.java on Line 25
android.app.Activity.performCreate in Activity.java on Line 5250
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate in Instrumentation.java on Line 1097
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity in ActivityThread.java on Line 2211
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity in ActivityThread.java on Line 2297
android.app.ActivityThread.access$700 in ActivityThread.java on Line 152
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage in ActivityThread.java on Line 1282
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage in Handler.java on Line 99
android.os.Looper.loop in Looper.java on Line 137
android.app.ActivityThread.main in ActivityThread.java on Line 5328
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke in Method.java on Line 511
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run in ZygoteInit.java on Line 1102
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main in ZygoteInit.java on Line 869
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream in BitmapFactory.java on Line 596
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream in BitmapFactory.java on Line 444
android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream in Drawable.java on Line 817
android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable in Resources.java on Line 2854
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable in TypedArray.java on Line 602
android.widget.ImageView.<init> in ImageView.java on Line 126
android.widget.ImageView.<init> in ImageView.java on Line 116
... 27 more
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream in BitmapFactory.java on Line 596
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream in BitmapFactory.java on Line 444
android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream in Drawable.java on Line 817
android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable in Resources.java on Line 2854
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable in TypedArray.java on Line 602
android.widget.ImageView.<init> in ImageView.java on Line 126
android.widget.ImageView.<init> in ImageView.java on Line 116
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance in Constructor.java on Line 417
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView in LayoutInflater.java on Line 593
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView in PhoneLayoutInflater.java on Line 56
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView in LayoutInflater.java on Line 666
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag in LayoutInflater.java on Line 691
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 752
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 495
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 397
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate in LayoutInflater.java on Line 353
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView in PhoneWindow.java on Line 327
android.app.Activity.setContentView in Activity.java on Line 1928
com.hdms.manager.Drawable.SplashScreen.onCreate in SplashScreen.java on Line 25
android.app.Activity.performCreate in Activity.java on Line 5250
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate in Instrumentation.java on Line 1097
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity in ActivityThread.java on Line 2211
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity in ActivityThread.java on Line 2297
android.app.ActivityThread.access$700 in ActivityThread.java on Line 152
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage in ActivityThread.java on Line 1282
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage in Handler.java on Line 99
android.os.Looper.loop in Looper.java on Line 137
android.app.ActivityThread.main in ActivityThread.java on Line 5328
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke in Method.java on Line 511
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run in ZygoteInit.java on Line 1102
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main in ZygoteInit.java on Line 869
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000" >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_image"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <!--<VideoView android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/videoView"/>-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code

```
package com.hdms.manager.Drawable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import com.hdms.manager.MainActivity;
import com.hdms.manager.R;

/**
 * Created by bradj on 8/10/13.
 *
 */

public class SplashScreen extends Activity
{
    // Splash screen timer
    private static final int mDisplaySplashScreen = 500;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, mDisplaySplashScreen);
    }
}
```

Comment: How large is your image?

Comment: The image is 768*1280 (24bit) 383kb

Comment: Can you post the image?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason the image isn't uploading. It's a png, if that helps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those stack reports are OutOfMemory exceptions, i.e. the device is out of memory.

Check in which drawable directory you are placing the background image, for 768x1280 px it should be drawable-xhdpi. Android automatically scales the image for other screen sizes, which means that if you place the image in drawable-mdpi it will be scaled to 2304x3840 for xxhdpi devices such as the Samsung 4.

Note that it is recommended to provide a bitmap resource for each supported screen size. See more about supporting multiple screen sizes here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Other than that there is little that you can do about OutOfMemoryException other than catching the exception with a try clause on setContentView and handling it gracefully. There are some really poor Android devices out there where memory problems are frequent. You should connect your App to a better error reporting system, where you get more device data, to confirm that this is the case.

Comment: I'll see how this goes the image was in the hdpi directory. I have now moved it to the correct directory. Thanks

Comment: I had all images in my drawables folder, moved them to drawable-xhdpi worked.