# Android Inflate exception with multiple screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an app that will support multiple screen sizes. Therefore I have created 3 layout folders i.e **layout,layout-small and layout-large**. 
But when I run this app in different phones its crashing on different screens and showing **binary inflate exception**.
Moreover in preview window in android studio its not picking layout from normal folder.It's showing small layout for both layout and layout-small.
Please point out my mistake and thanks in advance.
Adding layout-large for one of the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="be connected."
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_connect"
            android:textSize="54sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="be one."
            android:textSize="54sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#303359"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/video"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the error log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.webninjaz.one/com.webninjaz.one.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.webninjaz.one.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Could you please add your code?

Comment: all three layouts ??

Comment: Did you try picking different devices in preview window?

Comment: yes I did and for 4 inches and 6 inches devices it's picking layout-small for both

Comment: add your layout code and also add log message with your question

Comment: also the line number in XML where it is crashing!

Comment: refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874081/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8.Related to the image you are using in the ImageView.

Comment: add your log message also

Comment: added error logs already

Comment: large, small and xlarge qualifiers are deprecated use sw<N>dp for future also

Comment: one more question I am only having one set of images and placed them in drawable-xhdpi. Did this can cause problem

Comment: Are you using the same xml file name for your 3 layouts?

Comment: yes and I think its done the same way