# AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: android, android-studio

```
AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.tarun.calculator, PID: 3248
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
```

I have just created the xml file, And I am using the default MainActivity.java ,but while running I am getting these errors.
I am new to android programming ,any kind of help will be appreciated.
Logs

```
10-07 23:17:28.750    3248-3248/com.example.tarun.calculator E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.tarun.calculator, PID: 3248
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tarun.calculator/com.example.tarun.calculator.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                at com.example.tarun.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                at com.example.tarun.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                at com.example.tarun.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
         Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
                at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
                at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
                at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                at com.example.tarun.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/transform"

        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#59ffffff"
            android:textSize="60dp"
             android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"

        />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="*"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />


        </LinearLayout>




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"

                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"

                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="6"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="/"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />


        </LinearLayout>





        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            >

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="7"

                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="8"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />


        </LinearLayout>






        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="."
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"

                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="="
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#66ffffff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />


        </LinearLayout>










    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tarun.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20874326/5202007

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is the size of the image you are trying to load, as shown in the following error log line:

Caused by: java.lang.**OutOfMemoryError**: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your image on

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/transform"

        />
```

is too big for you device, i mean, the image resolution. Try to use a smaller image. Your stacktrace says that your problme is in the XML line 7.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it Happens due to Mobile Dark Them.

Just Change in styles

To
parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"
Now it will support both dark and light theme